# Cambiar formato a horizontal al exportar a excel de php

Tags: php, html5

Lo que sucede es que necesito exportar a excel un archivo, esto funciona bien, pero necesito que al exportar, el formato de la hoja sea HORIZONTAL(<--->) ya que en este momento sale vertical y los datos del formato solicitado no caben, agradezco su ayuda con una respuesta que me ayude.

El excel se crea a partir de una tabla de html que coloco en la acción del controlador de "COTIZACIONES"

[image: Adjunto imagen]
[image: Adjunto imagen 2]
Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: De preferencia el código que sea texto

Comment: Raul gracias por responder, realmente lo coloqué así sólo para que quién lo vea se haga una idea, pero el código me funciona bien, necesito es una manera de exportar a excel pero que el formato de la hoja quede horizontal.

Comment: usas alguna libreria para exportar a excel

Comment: Utilizo únicamente la librería de php "header", las primeras dos lineas de la acción de este controlador, como se ve en la primera imagen.